# Car Parts Software To View Parts of a Car

Tags: parts

Is there computer software that lets you see parts of a car for common car models, like European brands, and browse them in 3D. Is there anything that would have autocad schematics or something like that?

Comment: Do you need high-quality 3D models, or just actual parts microfiche diagrams that dealers and mechanics use (like [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/www.cheapcycleparts.com/images/manual/production/assembly_images/284008/large/TU250X-2011_6.png?1337221812))?

Comment: @theUg The purpose of the 3D models would be so that you could generate your own blown-up views like that one.  So, yes, if you have a source for those kinds of drawings, please post them.  I would like something that shows entire cars, not just the engines.  But something is better than nothing.

Comment: When I started the bounty I put up a comment which seems to have disappeared.  Here it is again.  Someone business-minded should make a deal with the manufacturers to host their design files online, along with animations like this one [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bsj-WCxCfrw).  A subscription site like that would blow the existing service information providers out of the water.

Comment: And after creating the 3D models, you could also create videos showing how to bend your arm to reach hidden parts.  This would be particularly useful for things under the dash.  People on forums often say, "reach your arm up to your elbow/shoulder/navel, twist your hand to the right of the vent and then you can pull the part out with your fingertips."  Videos of that process would be useful.

Comment: I once worked for Unigraphics, a 3d CAD/CAM vendor used by GM (and other companies) to design their cars, which could also be used to create those videos (to ensure serviceability).  So the tech is available.

Answer (score 1):

I dug around on this one, and didn't turn up too much. The best I found was 3dcadbrowser which contains a lot of downloadable 3ds files for CAD, but unfortunately not quite all of them are specific brands. Pretty good selection though.

http://www.3dcadbrowser.com/browse.aspx?category=52